# How can I export a default import as named?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a folder of utils which has an index.js file. To simplify utils usage throughout my app I am exporting everything in index.js.

So far I have been re-exporting only named modules like this:

```
export * from './Constants';
export { TIME } from './Time';
```

Is it possible to export a default as named?
This results in a syntax error:

`export default as { Constants } from './Constants';`

Comment: export { name1 as default, … }; ? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export

Comment: But that is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @mancristiana Joel was on the right track though. For the opposite, just `export { default as name1 }`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import * as Constants from './Constants';
const c = Constant.default;
export { c as Constant };
```

Here is a little plunkr demonstrating it : https://plnkr.co/edit/3WqzFQg33BG0iruD

Comment: That's not valid syntax

Comment: my bad, i fixed the syntax